# How to change quantity in cart laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, cart

I try to change the `quantity` in my `cart`.
My code looks like:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <input rowId="{{ $cart->rowId }}" type="number" value="{{ $cart->qty }}" class="form-control prc" required>
</div>
```

and my `script` is:

```
$('.form-group').on('input', '.prc', function(){
    var totalSum = 0;
    $('.form-group .prc').each(function()
    {
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        if ($.isNumeric(inputVal))
        {
            totalSum += parseFloat(inputVal);
        }
    });
    $('#result').text(totalSum);
    var rowId = $(this).attr('rowId');
    var quantity = $(this).val();
    var prevQuantity = $(this).attr('value');
    if ($.isNumeric(quantity) && (quantity != prevQuantity) && (quantity != 0))
    {
        window.location.href = "{{ url('Cart/add') }}"+'/'+rowId+'/'+quantity; 
    }
});
```

This is my `controller`:

```
 public function add($id, $quantity) 
{
    $item = Cart::get($id);
    Cart::update($id, ['qty'=>$quantity]);
    return redirect()->route('Cart.index');
}
```

But the value is not being stored in `cart->quantity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Ajax call for hitting your route.
Your route should be like this:

```
Route::get('/Cart/add/{rowId}/{qty}','YourController@add');
```

Your script should be like this:

```
$('.form-group').on('input', '.prc', function(){
    var totalSum = 0;
    $('.form-group .prc').each(function()
    {
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        if ($.isNumeric(inputVal))
        {
            totalSum += parseFloat(inputVal);
        }
    });
    $('#result').text(totalSum);
    var rowId = $(this).attr('rowId');
    var quantity = $(this).val();
    var prevQuantity = $(this).attr('value');
    if ($.isNumeric(quantity) && (quantity != prevQuantity) && (quantity != 0))
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '/Cart/add/'+rowId+'/'+quantity,
            success: function(data){
                if (data == 'success') {                
                    alert('success');
                }
                else{
                    alert('failure');
                }

            },
            error:function(data){

            }
        });
    }
});
```

> Note: I've just added the Ajax call here so make sure your script was
>   going in that if loop to work properly

And make your controller like this:

```
public function add($id, $quantity) {
    $item = Cart::find($id);
    $item->qty = $quantity;
    $item->save();
    return response('success');
}
```

It'll work hopefully

Comment: @irhamdollah Can you just give me your route code and proper code of controller

Comment: I have found the answer. Thank you

Comment: @irhamdollah It's my pleasure to help you